# MySQL seems to have a bug with distinct, avg, and group-by

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

The following query seems to behave incorrectly. With a group by on a single field and an average on that field distinct avg should probably return one row for every distinct average. If avg is replaced by count for example the query would return two rows and if distinct is removed or replaced by all then the query returns three rows.

```
CREATE TABLE x (x real);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (1), (2), (3), (3);
SELECT DISTINCT AVG(x) FROM x GROUP BY x;
```

MySQL returns:

```
+--------+
| AVG(x) |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

PostGres returns:

```
 AVG
-----
   1
   2
   3
```

Comment: What actually you need the reason or the solution that have same O/P

Comment: I'm testing my rdbms against mysql and this query breaks my random query generator.

Comment: It means you want the output like postgress am i right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query return this output :

```
 AVG
-----
   1
   2
   3
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  AVG(x) FROM x 
GROUP BY x;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56e49/2)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your select statement needs to be:

```
SELECT AVG(distinct x)
```